# Dynamics CRM: Get-CrmSetting SSL/TLS error

Tags: powershell

I am getting an error when trying to enable Tracing in one of our servers.

Commands used:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell
Get-CrmSetting TraceSettings
```

Error:

```
Get-CrmSetting : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the 
SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CrmSetting TraceSettings
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Crm.P...rmSettingCmdlet:GetCrmSettingCmdlet) [Get- 
   CrmSetting], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CRM Deployment Cmdlet Error,Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell.GetCrmSettingCmdlet
```

This is a multi-server environment where Web and Application are separate.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the certificate used on the end point you are trying to connect to is an un-trusted certificate.

I recommend ensuring that a valid and trusted certificate is used on the endpoint.

However if this is not possible you can set PowerShell to allow un-trusted certificates once per session with this function.

*However* be warned that running this function will disable **ALL** certificate checks that PowerShell would normally preform and the **only** way to reset this is to close and re-open PowerShell.

```
function Disable-SSLValidation
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Disables SSL certificate validation
.DESCRIPTION
    Disable-SSLValidation disables SSL certificate validation by using reflection to implement the System.Net.ICertificatePolicy class.
    Author: Matthew Graeber (@mattifestation)
    License: BSD 3-Clause
.NOTES
    Reflection is ideal in situations when a script executes in an environment in which you cannot call csc.ese to compile source code. If compiling code is an option, then implementing System.Net.ICertificatePolicy in C# and Add-Type is trivial.
.LINK
    http://www.exploit-monday.com
#>

    Set-StrictMode -Version 2

    # You have already run this function
    if ([System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy.ToString() -eq 'IgnoreCerts') { Return }

    $Domain = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain
    $DynAssembly = New-Object System.Reflection.AssemblyName('IgnoreCerts')
    $AssemblyBuilder = $Domain.DefineDynamicAssembly($DynAssembly, [System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess]::Run)
    $ModuleBuilder = $AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule('IgnoreCerts', $false)
    $TypeBuilder = $ModuleBuilder.DefineType('IgnoreCerts', 'AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, BeforeFieldInit', [System.Object], [System.Net.ICertificatePolicy])
    $TypeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor('PrivateScope, Public, HideBySig, SpecialName, RTSpecialName') | Out-Null
    $MethodInfo = [System.Net.ICertificatePolicy].GetMethod('CheckValidationResult')
    $MethodBuilder = $TypeBuilder.DefineMethod($MethodInfo.Name, 'PrivateScope, Public, Virtual, HideBySig, VtableLayoutMask', $MethodInfo.CallingConvention, $MethodInfo.ReturnType, ([Type[]] ($MethodInfo.GetParameters() | % {$_.ParameterType})))
    $ILGen = $MethodBuilder.GetILGenerator()
    $ILGen.Emit([Reflection.Emit.Opcodes]::Ldc_I4_1)
    $ILGen.Emit([Reflection.Emit.Opcodes]::Ret)
    $TypeBuilder.CreateType() | Out-Null

    # Disable SSL certificate validation
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object IgnoreCerts
}
```

Special thanks to [Matt Graeber](https://twitter.com/mattifestation) for authoring the code.

Comment: Doesn't `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }` do the same thing as all that stuff you posted?

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure, you'd get a better answer from Matt Graeber.